# How do I list each unique instance of a field within a group in Report Builder?

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

We have a report that shows the details of the day's sales, and is grouped by Salesrep, Customer, and Order Taker, Order. The layout would be similar to this:

1. Salesrep1

   - Taker1

     - Order1
     - Order2
     - Order3
   - Taker2

     - Order4
     - Order5
   - Taker3

     - Order6
     - Order7
2. Salesrep2

   - Taker1

     - Order8
     - Order9
   - Taker3

     - Order10
     - Order11
     - Order12
     - Order13
   - Taker4

     - Order 14

A taker can create several orders for several different salesreps.

Is it possible to show who all the Takers are for each Salesrep?

Comment: IS there a way you can add some example code or show what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Will, I have tried `=Lookup(Fields!Salesrep_ID.Value,Fields!Salesrep_ID.Value,Fields!taker.Value,"DataSet1")`, but it only retrieves the first Taker in each Salesrep group, rather than a list of all the Takers in the group.

Comment: Solved. I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047483/ssrs-distinct-lookupset-function

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it :)

Comment: @Will, I tried posting the solution as an Answer, but my post was considered a trivial response and turned into a comment :(

Comment: Sad, ok, no worries! :)