# How to convert multiple rows into one row in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, pivot, grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

My MSSQL sql query shows the data of Employee Hierarchy with the authcodes as below

```
ManagerName     EmployeeName    AuthCode
Tim             Peter           csr2
Tim             Peter           sup
Tim             Peter           itil
Tim             Colt            csr2
Tim             Colt            sup
```

   The SSRS report shows the results listed below, when I chose the report **parameter= Tim**, the result only shows the top line and not the subsequent AuthCodes whereas the query shows all

```
EmployeeName    AuthCode
Peter           csr2
Colt            csr2
```

   I want the data to show like(it should concatenate the authcodes for the employees):

```
EmployeeName    AuthCode
Peter           csr2, sup, itil
Colt            csr2, sup
```

Could anyone please suggest what I need to do in SSRS so that the data shows all the authcodes with comma separated values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: @GeetanjaliSachdeva, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047483/ssrs-distinct-lookupset-function)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
=JOIN(LOOKUPSET(Fields!EmployeeName.Value, Fields!EmployeeName.Value, Fields!AuthCode.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

The **LookupSet** get all the AuthCodes based on the EmployeeName.

The **JOIN** converts the array into a string using a comma delimiter.

Comment: +Hannover Fist Thanks! That works but i still see some authcodes that are duplicated in a cell for the same employee. How can i get rid off the duplicates?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the **JOIN** nor the **LookupSet** can handle duplicates. Can you make your data DISTINCT? Otherwise you'd need some custom VB code to parse out the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Some addition to Hannover Fist's answer:
If you need distinct your join + lookupset result, you can

Go to your Report's properties -> `Code` [tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnTuW.png)

Add some VB code to your report properties

```vb
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(m_Array As Object()) As String()

    System.Array.Sort(m_Array)
    Dim k As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To m_Array.Length - 1
        If i > 0 AndAlso m_Array(i).Equals(m_Array(i - 1)) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        m_Array(k) = m_Array(i)
        k += 1
    Next

    Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
    System.Array.Copy(m_Array, 0, unique, 0, k)
    Return unique

End Function
```

and edit cell expression:

```vb
=JOIN( Code.RemoveDuplicates( LOOKUPSET(Fields!EmployeeName.Value, Fields!EmployeeName.Value, Fields!AuthCode.Value, "DataSet1")), ", ")
```