# Display a column values in Report Header

Tags: reporting-services

need to pass one column in Lookupset and  I am doing as below

```
="Billing Code: "+Code.JoinDistinct(LookupSet(Fields!BillingCode.Value, Fields!BillingCode.Value, Fields!BillingCode.Value, "DataSet1"),",")
```

and the Function is

```
public shared function JoinDistinct(
  dups as object(),
  delimiter as string
) as string

  dim result as string = ""
  system.array.sort(dups)

  for i as integer = 0 to dups.length - 1
    if i <> 0 then result += delimiter
    if i = 0 orElse dups(i) <> dups(i-1) then result += dups(i)
  next i

  return result

end function
```

**Result**

Billing Code: ,,,A,,,,,,

How Can I remove extra commas

Comment: What is your question and how is it not working?  What result are you getting?

Comment: I want to display column values in report header without duplicates separated by a comma

Comment: ...I got that but what isn't working?  What result are you getting?

Comment: when it's single value based on parameters it's working and when multiple values need to displayed its blank

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is certainly possible, but requires a bit of a workaround. The `Join` function is designed to work on an array of values. The column you used, even though it may have multiple rows at that scope, is not an array. You can use the `LookupSet` function to get the rows as an array and pass them into the `Join` function. If there may be duplicate values that you want to remove, you'll have to add custom code to handle that.

Here's an example of how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27141955/2033717

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Join(LookupSet(Fields!itemId.Value , "Dataset1"), ",")  I am using above as lookupset given an error

Comment: `LookupSet` takes 4 arguments, not 2. See the link I shared or the official documentation on it for more detail.

Comment: Steven, Updated my question. please answer it when you have a moment

Comment: The original question had to do with getting the `Join` and `LookupSet` functions working. And it looks like they are now. If this custom function "JoinDistinct" is producing unexpected results, that would be a different question. I'm not familiar with the syntax used there. You might be able to find some similar examples that work better for you.