# RDLC | TextBox Join distinct on Group

Tags: ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have RDLC Tablix which has data below. My table is grouped by ***1st column***.

[image]

the red highlighted column shows the *join value comma separated* with respected to the *1st column*.
However there is repeating **1,1** in **1st row**.

Main data set looks like something below
[image]

Question:

- How to avoid the repeating value in join statement. following is the textbox expression I have tried now

`=Join(LookUpSet(Fields!Col1.Value, Fields!Col1.Value, Fields!Col3.Value, "DSName"), ",")`

Comment: Have a look at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047483/ssrs-distinct-lookupset-function

Comment: The link given by Alan seems promising. Personally I'd just change the data source's query to perform grouping there if possible.