Concatenating one instance of the columns of rows of a dataset
In an rdlc report of the report viewer I have dataset named dataSet1.  Suppose it returns values
1     Name1
2     Name2
3     Name1
4     Name2

I want to have a function which returns Name1, Name2.
How should I do that?

You can use LOOKUPSET and JOIN to do this.
Something like
=JOIN(LOOKUPSET(1,1,Fields!myName.Value,"myDataSetName"), ", ")

Using LOOKUPSET() we match arbitrary values of 1 and 1 so all data is selected. We then want to return the value of the myName field and finally, we state we wanted to return everything in the "myDataSetName" dataset.
Once we have these values, we JOIN() them with ", " as the delimiter.
You can use this expression in a table or simple standalone textbox.

I've just noticed that  you wanted distinct values only. Look at these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047483/ssrs-distinct-lookupset-function
